# What is the use of this Command bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -m?

Tags: magento2, command, translation-dictionaries

What is the use of this below command?

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -m
```

explain me briefly.

Thanks,

Comment: You can fine here I think - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict

Answer (score 1):

*Absolute file system path and file name of a .csv file that contains the combined translation dictionary and meta-information necessary for breakdown into a language package.*

*Use bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases to create the .csv file then create the language package as discussed in Create directories and files.*

*-m --mode  If a target file already exists, specifies whether to replace the existing language package or merge with the new language pack. Merging overrides any phrases that existed and adds new ones.*

*Values: merge or replace (default).*

> For More details :
>
> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html